# Changing property or state from inside and outside component

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Need to control some variable(for example Boolean) from both sides, from inside component and outside. Or better say I need to know state of the component outside component

```
onClick() {
  this.setState({showToggle: true})
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" onClick={this.onClick}
      <ToggleComponent
        show={this.state.showToggle}
      />

    </div>
  )
)
```

and ToggleComponent inside it

```
onHide() {
  this.props.show = false; //<--- it does not works but want something like that 
}

render() {
  if (!this.props.show) {
    return (
    );
  }
  
  return (<div>..........<input type="button" value="Hide" onClick={this.onHide}/></div>)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok...I created own solution for this....

The magic is in wrapping prop into object.

In parent component

```
this.com1Handler = {state: false};
  return (<div>..........<input type="button" value="Hide" onClick={this.props.onHide}/></div>)

onClick() {
  this.com1Handler.state = true;
  this.setState({});
}

render() {
  return (
    <input type="button" value="go"  onClick={this.onClick}/>
    <Child myHandle={this.com1Handler} />
  )

}
```

in child:

```
onClick() {
  this.props.myHandle.state = false
  this.setState({});
}

render() {
  if (!this.props.myHandle.state) return '';

return (<div>..........
      <input type="button" value="Hide" onClick={this.onClick}/>
      </div>)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement onHide function in the parent component and pass it as props.

The new code can look something like this:

```
onClick() {
  this.setState({showToggle: true})
}

onHide() {
   this.setState({showToggle: false})
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" onClick={this.onClick}
      <ToggleComponent
        show={this.state.showToggle} onHide={this.onHide}
      />

    </div>
  )
)
```

and ToggleComponent

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.show) {
    return (
    );
  }
  
  return (<div>..........<input type="button" value="Hide" onClick={this.props.onHide}/></div>)
)
```

Comment: this seems not an answer. i want to hide from inside component, so state becomes false, that again from outside make it show.

Comment: @Subdigger this is the way only. You can't override props that you're passing. You have to define function in parent component and pass it to child, then call that function from child.

Comment: @Subdigger This seems like answer to me as this is how React is designed to work. Data flows down the Tree, from parent to child. See [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: @shyammakwana.me im not looking for way to override props. im looking a way to have one (if its possible) set of params that i can controll, better inside the component. in other way there is no profit in that component i just can put all inside one funny file....

Comment: @DrewReese yea saw that and using for some cases. Just checking if i missed something and thare is a better way

Comment: if you have state that's on parent level, there's only one way you can control from child. which is in this answer. There's profit indeed. For that I'd suggest you to have a look at `functional components`.

Answer (score 0):

Without providing to a child component a function that changes `show` in parent component You will not be able to actually change it.
States alone wont bind like this `this.state.show = false`. a `this.setState({show:!this.state.show})` must be used. Same goes with `this.props`, but `this.props` does not provide `this.setProps()`, You have to "provide" it Yourself.

With states in class-less components, one can do something like that:

```js
function Parent() {
    const [state,setState] = React.useState(false);

   return (
    <Child state={state} setState={setState} /> 
    )
}

function Child(props) {
    
    // with this button, state in Parent will change
    return (
    <button onClick={() => {props.setState(!props.state)}>Click</button>
    )
}
```

Without a `state managment system` (which is overkill for this), You might not be able to do this.